# How to Get Some Basic Info from a DLL File?

Tags: windows, dll

Assume you have a .DLL file, and you want to know some basic information regarding it,
for example:

1. Is it a Managed (.NET) or Non-Managed (e.g. COM, etc) DLL
2. If it's Managed, what minimal version of .NET it requires
   (and if it's non-managed, then any other minimal version that it requires? for example minimal version of Windows, or of something else)
3. Any other kind of such metadata

Please note that I am less interested in seeing the Function Headers (or Classes) that are inside.
Visual Studio's `Object Browser` can show the Functions/Classes very well,
yet I did not find a way to make Object Browser show the metadata that I mentioned above..

So maybe another utility can do it?